# Reorder column values when there is a uniqueness constraint

Tags: sql-server

I have a table `Devices` with PK `Id` and additional column `Serial` which has a uniqueness constraint. Turns out we were given incorrect Serial numbers - they got them mixed up so several need swapping around.

### Existing

```
Id   Serial
-    -
1    lkji89
2    jh6566
3    lkl387
4    lkl58u
```

### Should be

```
Id   Serial
-    -
1    lkl387
2    lkji89
3    lkl58u
4    jh6566
```

As soon as I try to change one, `Serial` collides and violates the uniqueness constraint. This table is also linked via FK to other tables and there is data in the system so I can't (I think) quickly drop and re-create the data.

How can I make these changes effectively?

Comment: @sagi that doesn't exactly scale very well - fine to fix one or two rows, unless there is a nice scripting solution?

Comment: How could we script this if you didn’t provide the logic for the swaps?

Comment: How do you decide which serial should be associated with which id?

Comment: @Mr.Boy your actual question is how to *replace* those values, not reorder them. Even if the values can be produced from the original table, it's still replacing, ie `UPDATE`. You can use `UPDATE` by joining with a table source, a `VALUES` constructor to provide the new values or even a `SELECT ROW_NUMBER()..., Serial From... Order By Serial`. The best option depends on how many entries there are. It's faster to type or copy/paste values in `VALUES` for a few serials than it would be to write and test the `SELECT` query

Comment: @Mr.Boy you could even open the table for editing in SSMS and just paste the correct values.

Comment: @sagi there is no logic, it's customer provided data. They provided the wrong data :)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I hadn't realised I could paste in that way. You mean like from Excel? My 'more serious' thought was to load the correct data into a temporary table and do a match update or use transactions but that's outside my expertise level really.

Comment: @Mr.Boy you can write an `UPDATE` whose `FROM` joins the target table with another result set. That could be another table, `VALUES` or a `SELECT`. To get serials in order. you'd need an `ORDER BY Serial`. `ROW_NUMBER()` will produce the IDs needed for the JOIN

Comment: @Mr.Boy how many rows are there?

Answer (score 2):

You can perform the operations all at once with a single set-based update statement. Below is an example using `CASE`:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Example(
     Id int CONSTRAINT PK_Example PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    ,Serial varchar(10) CONSTRAINT UQ_Example_Serial UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED
);
INSERT INTO dbo.Example VALUES
     (1, 'lkji89')
    ,(2, 'jh6566')
    ,(3, 'lkl387')
    ,(4, 'lkl58u');

UPDATE dbo.Example
SET Serial = CASE 
    WHEN Id = 1 THEN 'lkl387'
    WHEN Id = 2 THEN 'lkji89'
    WHEN Id = 3 THEN 'lkl58u'
    WHEN Id = 4 THEN 'jh6566'
    END;
```

Another method in SQL Server is with a `JOIN` to a table with the corrected values:

```
DECLARE @Corrections TABLE(
     Id int PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    ,Serial varchar(10) UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED
);

INSERT INTO @Corrections (Id, Serial) VALUES
     (1, 'lkl387')
    ,(2, 'lkji89')
    ,(3, 'lkl58u')
    ,(4, 'jh6566');

UPDATE dbo.Example
SET Serial = corrections.Serial
FROM @Corrections AS corrections
WHERE corrections.Id = dbo.Example.Id;
```

Comment: I'd not come across this syntax before, thanks - I'm a developer who does some SQL not a MSSQL expert :)

Comment: @Mr.Boy all SQL variants allow this one way or another, this isn't specific to SQL Server. There are other techniques, depending on the size and the database product. You can't use ROW_NUMBER() to produce IDs in MySQL 5.x for example, you'd have to use MySQL 8. All products have their own CASE, CHOOSE or something similar

Comment: BTW this could be replaced with `SET Serial= CHOOSE(ID,'lkl387',..)` perhaps?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos. `CHOOSE` would work for these specific `Id` values but not as a generalized solution where the `ID` values don't start at 1 or have large gaps.

Answer (score 1):

When that other guy (never us) messes up data, one quick fix can be pasting the correct data in the `Edit` view in SSMS.

Apart from that, the rows can be swapped around as long as the operation happens in a single UPDATE query.

If the number or entries is small, one can just type them in the query. Dan Guzman posted such a solution. A similar one can use CHOOSE (which I've never used before) :

```
update example
set serial=choose(id,  'lkl387','lkji89','lkl58u', 'jh6566')
```

An UPDATE query can contain a FROM clause with a self join. This could be used to JOIN with a subquery or a `VALUES` clause that produces the desired data:

```
update example
set serial = x.serial
from example inner join 
    (VALUES  (1, 'lkl387')
            ,(2, 'lkji89')
            ,(3, 'lkl58u')
            ,(4, 'jh6566')) x(id,serial) on x.id=example.id
```

If the serials could be ordered, one could even use the original data:

```
UPDATE dbo.Example
SET Serial =x.Serial
from Example inner join 
    (select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Serial) ID,
            Serial 
    from Example ) x on x.id=example.ID
```